# How to convert a JSON file to Delimited File using perl.

Tags: json, perl

```
#/usr/lib/perl

use lib qw(..);
use JSON qw( );

open json_fh, "<$ARGV[0]" or die "Couldn't open file $ARGV[0]!\n";
open csv_fh, ">$ARGV[1]" or die "Couldn't open file $ARGV[1]!\n";

@json_text =<json_fh>;
close json_fh;
foreach $json_text( @json_text )
{
    chomp $json_text;
    $json = JSON->new;
    $data = $json->decode($json_text);

    $id=$data->{_id};
    @lines=@{$data->{accounts}};
    foreach $line ( @lines )
    {
        $accountNumber = $line->{accountNumber};
        $accountType = $line->{accountType};
        $cardType = $line->{cardType};
        $cardSubType = $line->{cardSubType};
        $protectionMethod = $line->{protectionMethod};
        $protectionSource = $line->{protectionSource};
        $expirationDate = $line->{expirationDate};
        $nameOnAccount = $line->{nameOnAccount};
        $cardStatus = $line->{cardStatus};
        $cardHolderType = $line->{cardHolderType};
        $createdBy = $line->{createdBy};
        $addressId = $line->{addressId};
        $productType = $line->{productType};
        $isDefaultAccount = $line->{isDefaultAccount};

        #Write to the file in delimited file format
        print csv_fh "$id|$accountNumber|$accountType|$cardType|$cardSubType|$protectionMethod|$protectionSource|$expirationDate|$nameOnAccount|$cardStatus|$cardHolderType|$createdBy|$addressId|$productType|$isDefaultAccount\n";
    }
}
close csv_fh;
```

This is a perl script that, I created to convert the JSON file to a delimited file, If the element names are known.

Could anyone please help me to modify the code so that this conversion can be done, when the element names are unknown.

Comment: Your code looks quite old-fashioned. Please add `use strict` and `use warnings` and make it compile with these pragmata. We don't like to deal with error-prone code here because it makes helping people really hard. Thanks.

Comment: What order would the columns be in? What's the format of the JSON structure?

Comment: Arrays, not scalars. `{ local $" = "|"; say "@row"; }` for simple stuff, an actual CSV module for anything that might have embedded pipes or other non-trivial content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that every account has the same fields —it makes no sense otherwise— you can use the following:

```
my $json_parser = JSON->new;

my @headers;
for my $json_doc (@json_docs) {
   my $data = $json_parser->decode($json_doc);

   my $id = $data->{_id};
   for my $account (@{ $data->{accounts} }) {
      if (!@headers) {
         @headers = sort keys %$account;
         say join "|", 'id', @headers;
      }

      say join "|", $id, @$account{@headers};
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an example input file, so I'm guessing it is something like this:

```
{ "accounts": [ { "_id": "1", "accountNumber": "99999", "accountType": "acctTypeA", "cardType": "cardTypeA", "cardSubType": "cardSubTypeA", "protectionMethod": "protectionMethodA", "protectionSource": "protectionSourceA", "expirationDate": "2020-09", "nameOnAccount": "First Last", "cardStatus": "OK", "cardHolderType": "CHTypeA", "createdBy": "userX", "addressId": "444", "productType": "prodTypeA", "isDefaultAccount": "1", "optional": "OptA" } ] }
```

You're pretty close, but usually the entire file is a JSON record, so you don't loop line-by-line, you create a data structure (hashref) that represents the entire file (i.e. you only need to do $json->decode once per file).

Additionally, I'd suggest some checks to validate input, such as missing fields; you can see I have it die with an error message if any field is missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use lib qw(..);
use JSON qw( );

@ARGV == 2 or die("Infile, Outfile required\n");
open json_fh, "<$ARGV[0]" or die "Couldn't open file $ARGV[0]!\n";
open csv_fh, ">$ARGV[1]" or die "Couldn't open file $ARGV[1]!\n";

my $json_text =<json_fh>;
close json_fh;

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);
my $accounts = $data->{accounts};

my @required = qw(_id accountNumber accountType cardType cardSubType protectionMethod protectionSource expirationDate nameOnAccount cardStatus cardHolderType createdBy addressId productType isDefaultAccount); 
my @opt = (); # learn these
my %col; # key => column index
my $lastIndex;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#required; ++$i) { $lastIndex = $col{$required[$i]} = $i }
print "There are ", $lastIndex+1, " required cols\n";

foreach my $rec ( @$accounts )
{
    my @row;    
    foreach my $key ( keys %$rec )
    {
        if ( ! exists($col{$key}) ) {
            # new (optional) key
            push @opt, $key;
            $col{$key} = ++$lastIndex;
            print "New col: $key (col ", $lastIndex+1, ")\n";
        }
        $row[$col{$key}] = $rec->{$key};
    }

    # check for all required
    for (my $i=0; $i<=$#required; ++$i) {
        defined($row[$i]) or die("Missing: $required[$i]\n");
    }

    #Write to the file in delimited file format
    print csv_fh join("|", @row), "\n";
}
close csv_fh;
```

Comment: If we assume that the OP code is correct, then `@lines=@{$data->{accounts}};` suggests that the structure would be `{ accounts: [...] }`, that is, the list is not a hash but an array.

Comment: @Corion : yes, fixed example json as indicated

Comment: @ikegami : yes, forgot that, added to answer

Comment: @EdwardKirton My JSON file has 2.3 million records in it.

Comment: @EdwardKirton My JSON file has 2.3 million records in it. I was wondering that, can we parse the JSON file only if structure of the JSON file is known?

Comment: You said you fixed it, but you still hardcode the field names, so this doesn't answer the question

Comment: Re "*can we parse the JSON file only if structure of the JSON file is known?*", @Shon Cleneeto, You need to know the structure if you want to change the structure (as you want to do), but you don't need to know the specific fields names, as my answer shows.